# Why does opening an admin command prompt from an unelevated command prompt not allow output redirection of the command prompt itself?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

If you copy cmd.exe and set it to open as administrator and rename it to admin.exe and then do `admin > file.txt`, it does not redirect the stdout of the command prompt itself, but it works if you are using an admin command prompt already and then do `admin > file.txt`. In this case it also does not open up a new window. It makes sense than it needs to open up a new conhost for an admin session, but I don't see why it doesn't let you redirect the output. Is is a security feature?

This reminds me of the issue where you can't open up a new cmd.exe window using `start cmd` and redirect the output of cmd.exe directly, because the start command does not support redirection. Instead, you must spawn another cmd that uses that conhost and then redirect the output of that i.e. `start cmd /c cmd ^> file.txt`, so you can't actually test whether it's because it's opening up a new window and conhost instance or whether it's because it's an admin console application -- obviously you could actually test this by trying to CreateProcess on an admin application and see whether programmatically changing the handles succeeds, and then testing to see whether it succeeds with CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, and there appears to be something related to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18660014/redirect-standard-output-and-prompt-for-uac-with-processstartinfo).

Comment: `>` is something that is internal to cmd.exe so is only supported by cmd.exe..

Comment: @user1292580 cmd > file.txt or anyprogram.exe > file.txt works, it's only when you do cmd and get it to open another console window and hence new conhost process that it doesn't redirect

Comment: I'm not sure why you keep going on about conhost. Conhost doesn't do redirection. It allows consoles to be created at different privilege levels to prevent lower privilege processes from interacting with higher ones.

Comment: @user1292580 because in the event opening cmd.exe causes a new conhost window to be opened (AllocConsole), the standard handles will be certain magic numbers that are sent to conhost in an ALPC request, whereas a child cmd simply attaches to the console the parent is attached to (AttachConsole), which will just mean giving it the same numbers and setting up a buffer to communicate with conhost... I don't really see why the redirection command wouldn't work in the former case, so perhaps it is because it's opening an admin cmd

Comment: I'm using conhost to emphasise a new console window being opened, because that's what contains the console buffer and the input buffer and what actually handles the GUI messages. I'm trying to think of a way to get a cmd.exe to open in another console to test whether it's that or whether it's because it's opening an admin console, because right now opening an admin console is the only way I can get it to open another console window (and start is no use because redirection doesn't work with it). surely it can specify the handles in CreateProcess along with CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, which usually does

Comment: AttachConsole is not used by child consoles. They automatically get one.

Comment: @user1292580 but the child attaches to the console window thats open if the child doesn't open a new console window right? To do this, attachconsole would be called before the base thread is spawned to jump to the entry point of the console application executable... This is what I always thought